# Wifi keeps timing out (RTL8822CE)

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, network-interface, realtek

I recently bought a **Honor Magicbook 14** on which I installed Kali Linux (Latest version). The wifi is working, but is timing out every 30s-2min for about 30s. I already tried installing the `rtw88` driver from GitHub which also does not work (The driver should actually be included in the current kernel).

I also tested with another external wifi adapter and that works without any problems.

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0 IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXX"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 24:65:11:B6:DF:08   
      Bit Rate=104 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:123  Invalid misc:270   Missed beacon:0
```

**lspci | grep -i wireless**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

**lspci -knn |grep Net -A2**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c822]
        Subsystem: Electronics & Telecommunications RSH RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1058:1e25]
        Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
        Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce
```

**smod | grep rtw**

```
rtw88_8822ce           16384  0
rtw88_8822c           331776  1 rtw88_8822ce
rtw88_pci              28672  1 rtw88_8822ce
rtw88_core            159744  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8822c
mac80211              983040  7 mt76,rtw88_pci,mt76_usb,mt76x02_lib,rtw88_core,mt76x02_usb,mt76x2u
cfg80211              974848  5 mt76,mt76x02_lib,rtw88_core,mac80211,mt76x02_usb
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux kali 5.10.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1kali1 (2021-02-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know what to do, my laptop can not be used without wifi... Maybe a driver problem?

Comment: Tried https://github.com/bserem/Realtek-RTL8822x-Linux and https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Comment: It is better to open a new issue [here,](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) maybe a general bug.

Comment: Yes, but I mean the driver is included in the kernel now. Maybe it is another problem?

Comment: I did add it now.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -rv rtw88_8822ce` then `sudo modprobe -v rtw_8822ce`

Comment: `sudo modprobe -v rtw_8822ce
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_8822ce not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.0-kali3-amd64` So it was removed

Comment: Try to install it from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Comment: Still timing out after some time. I rebooted my laptop.